# Handlebars template inside Handlebars

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Im trying to render a Handlebars template using NodeJS and Backbone.

So far, what i have done works perfectly when inside an HTML file:

```
app.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
 ...    
 render: function() {           
   var template = Handlebars.compile( $("#my-template").html());        
   this.$el.html( template(this.model.toJSON()) );
   return this;
 }
 ...
});
```

View inside HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="my-template">
   {{text}}
</script>
```

However, if I place this view inside a Handlebars template, it does not work because {{text}} is being interpreted by NodeJS Handlebars compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="my-template">
   \{{text}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using a helper named "braces":

```
...
exports.braces = function(obj1){
   return '{{'+param+'}}';
}
...
```

And using:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="my-template">
   {{{braces 'text'}}}
</script>
```

Is there any way of doing this without using helpers?

Comment: vkurchatkin's solution is a tad easier ;)

Comment: Worked for me with: Node.js using Express.js using express-hbs package.

Answer (score 0):

You can define helpers in `app.js` like

`app.engine(
  '.hbs',
  hbs({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'base',
    ...
    helpers: {
      default: hbsHelper(), // this is the default helpers if you have like handlerbars-helpers
      raw() { return 'your templates' }
    }
  })
);`

In your case, it is

`raw() { return 
'<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="my-template">
   {{text}}
</script>' }`  replace ' with ` in your code.

Then in your front end files(.hbs for example), just include `{{{raw}}}`, and you can work with your templates without rendering. So that you can write normal templates without any other modifications, since `{{{raw}}}` will just render it as html.